# show errors on two form fields after errors on validating uniqueness with `scope`

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have a model that has

```
attr_accessible :name, :activity

validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :activity }
```

It works and it doesn't allow the creation of duplicate entries. But with simple_form it only shows the error on the `:name` field. I'd like it to have errors on both fields saying that this 'name' and 'activity' combination has already been taken.

I'm thinking I need to create a custom validation method, but I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution that I've overlooked so far.

Is there a way to show errors on both these fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing

```
validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :activity, message: 'This name and activity combination has already been taken.' }
```

I haven't decided if I'm going to have it validate both and put the message on both fields yet, but that opposite for the `:activity` field would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another validation on :activity so that it will be marked as duplicate as well:

```
validates :activity, uniqueness: { scope: :name }
```

I'm not sure that's the most elegant solution but it will spare you the custom validation method.

Comment: That's true. I tried both, but I didn't think about leaving them both on.But I still need to show that they are connected in some way. If no one else comes up with anything I'll check this as the answer.